# Override JavaFX CSS style in code

Tags: css, overriding, javafx-8

Is it possible to override a JavaFX CSS definition in code?

For example, in my CSS file I defined a button's height as follows:

```
.button {
    -fx-pref-height: 30px;
}
```

When I try to override this height for some button in code...

```
Button button = new Button();
button.setPrefSize(100, 50); // width, height
```

...the button still has a height of 30 pixels.

Comment: It should work. Can you create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE)?

Comment: @Rvervuurt: It's Java, not HTML

Comment: MCVE: http://bikusta.de/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/javafx-css-mcve.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two solutions:

1. Make sure that `button.setPrefSize(100, 50); // width, height` is called after the `Button` became visible.
2. Use Bindings to force its size (CSS does not overwrite bound values), for example: `button.prefHeightProperty().bind(new SimpleDoubleProperty(60));`

Comment: The second solution is working. I also found a third one: button.setStyle("-fx-pref-height: 60px");